# Jhipster Social login with facebook doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, angular5, jhipster, spring-social

i have created Jhipster monolithic project which include social login,
and i set client-id and secret-id but when click signin with facebook doesn't work,
i get this message ' Cannot POST /signin/facebook ',

Answer (score 0):

Please don't cross post with our ticket system, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7394
We would have more time to answer people if we didn't need to sort cross posts and duplicate issues

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error for jhipster4.

New section in pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

New version for facebook module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```